# How to remove relative image path with PHP

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework

I am trying to remove all the relative image path slashes from HTML content that contains several other elements.

Please see example bellow:

```
<img src="../../../../images/upload/myimage.jpg />
```

The link above should become:

```
<img src="http://mydomain.com/images/upload/myimage.jpg" />
```

How to do this using PHP with combining a regex!

Thx!

Comment: Please can anyone tell me why I got 2 down votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
$string = '<img src="../../../../images/upload/myimage.jpg />';
$pattern = '/(\.\.\/)+/';
$replacement = 'http://mydomain.com/';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: This is the most complete solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
".*(/images.*)"
```

and replace it with:

```
http://mydomain.com$1
```

Comment: Please can you elaborate this a little bit more?

Comment: @Mr.M, It matches everything until /images and replaces it with the baseurl.

Answer (score 1):

You can match:

`(<img src=")(\.\.\/)+(.*)`

and replace with:

`\1http://mydomain.com/\3`

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/fT9kA9)</kbd>